# MYSQL How to input externally calculated value into row

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I'm having some issues with this MySQL query. I've got two tables, one that has a list of all the "Leaders of the Opposition"(People elected into office) with the date that they were elected. And I've got another table of all the people they've been married to, and the year they got married in.

I'm trying to make a query that returns all the Leaders of the Opposition ordered by their appointment date with their current spouses name at the time and the date of their marriage.

Here is some practice data of just one leader, dates changed a bit to fit the sort of problem I'm trying to solve.

TABLE ONE:

Leader_of_Opposition------Date Elected

Beazley K C, 1996-03-19

Beazley K C, 2005-01-28

TABLE TWO:

Leader_of_Opposition----Spouses's Name----Year Married

Beazley K C, Mary Ciccarelli, 1974

Beazley K C, Susie Annus, 2004

### -

And I'm trying to get it to something like this:

Leader_of_Opposition------Date Elected------Spouses's name--------Year Married

Beazley K C, 1996-03-19, Mary Ciccarelli, 1974

Beazley K C, 2005-01-28, Susie Annus, 2004

### -

So far I've got the basics of:

SELECT opposition.leader_name, opposition.time_begin, opposition_marriage.spouse_name, opposition_marriage.year_married'

FROM opposition, opposition_marriage

AND opposition.leader_name=opposition_marriage.leader_name

ORDER BY opposition.time_begin

But it gives me results where the leaders are mentioned multiple times for each marriage. And I can't figure out the syntax to search the other table then place that value into the row.

Any help would be extremely appreciated, been banging my head up against this one for a while now.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is going to be easiest with correlated subqueries.  Alas, though, your tables do not have unique identifiers for each row.

```
SELECT o.leader_name, o.time_begin,
       (select om.spouse_name
        from opposition_marriage om
        where o.leader_name = om.leader_name and om.year_married <= year(o.date_elected)
        order by om.year_married desc
        limit 1
       ) as spouse_name,
       (select om.year_married
        from opposition_marriage om
        where o.leader_name = om.leader_name and om.year_married <= year(o.date_elected)
        order by om.year_married desc
        limit 1
       ) as year_married
FROM opposition o
ORDER BY o.time_begin;
```

This handles as many marriages as you like.

Now some comments:

- It seems really strange to have a table only of marriages for the opposition leaders and not for all politicians.
- The granularity is at the level of a "year", so a leader married in the same year after s/he takes office counts as being married to that spouse.
- You do not have a "marriage end date", so a divorced or widowed partner would be considered current until the next marriage.
- As I mention in the beginning, you should have a unique identifier for each row.